# Remove unwanted Addthis plugin built into purchased WordPress theme?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am customizing a website theme for a client. When I went to run speed tests, I noticed that this bit of code

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js?domready=1&#038;ver=1'></script>
```

was creating a couple dozen redirects to spammy areas. It only exists on the home page, and not any other pages. The Addthis plugin appears to be built into the theme, and I cannot find where to remove it. I don't want to sacrifice speed for a plugin I don't need.

I checked the footer.php file, then functions.php, and then literally every single file in the theme where this thing could be called. I used Dreamweaver to search the theme's entire folder for any document containing that code, and Dreamweaver found nothing. If I activate a different theme, the code goes away, so I know it's the theme doing it. I just can't figure out how!

Does anyone know where/what I should be looking for? I have been searching everywhere for an answer and haven't been able to find one. Could this be something caused by a javascript file? Or encrypted PHP?

Hopefully helpful info:

The theme is Mercor and it's a WooCommerce-ready theme. Here is the demo page: http://mercor.premiumcoding.com/ . You can see around line 1369 where the offending snippet is.

Footer in functions.php:

```
    function footer(){
function pmc_recent_footer_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 40;
}

function pmc_recent_footer_title($title) { return  substr($title, 0, 40). '';}

add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'pmc_recent_footer_excerpt_length', 999 );
add_filter('the_title', 'pmc_recent_footer_title') ;
    }
```

If I remove that entire snippet the offending code AND the whole footer go away. I tried removing everything inside the brackets, like this:

```
function footer(){ 
}
```

but the offending code still showed up.

Also in functions.php - but deleting did not help

```
    function socialLinkCat($link,$title,$email) {
$social = '';
$social .='<div class="addthis_toolbox"><div class="custom_images">';
global $data; 
if($data['facebook_show'] == 1)
$social .= '<a class="addthis_button_facebook" addthis:url="'.$link.'" addthis:title="'.$title.'"  title="'.$data['translation_facebook'].'"><img src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/images/facebookIcon.png" width="64" height="64" border="0" alt="'.$data['translation_facebook'].'" /></a>';            
if($data['twitter_show'] == 1)
$social .= '<a class="addthis_button_twitter" addthis:url="'.$link.'" addthis:title="A'.$title.'"  title="'.$data['translation_twitter'].'"><img src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/images/twitterIcon.png" width="64" height="64" border="0" alt="'.$data['translation_twitter'].'" /></a>';  
if($data['digg_show'] == 1) 
$social .= '<a class="addthis_button_digg" addthis:url="'.$link.'" addthis:title="'.$title.'" title="'.$data['translation_digg'].'"><img src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/images/diggIcon.png" width="64" height="64" border="0" alt="'.$data['translation_digg'].'" /></a>';  
if($data['stumble_show'] == 1)
$social .= '<a class="addthis_button_stumble" addthis:url="'.$link.'" addthis:title="'.$title.'" title="'.$data['translation_stumble'].'"><img src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/images/stumbleUponIcon.png" width="64" height="64" border="0" alt="Share to Stumble Upon" /></a>';  

$social .='<a class="addthis_button" addthis:url="'.$link.'" addthis:title="'.$title.'" ><img src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/images/socialIconShareMore.png" width="64" height="64" border="0" alt="More..." /></a></div><script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-4f3049381724ac5b"></script>'; 
if($data['email_show'] == 1 && $email) 
$social .= '<a class="emaillink" href="mailto:'.$data['email'].'" title="'.$data['translation_email'].'"></a></div>'; 
$social .= '</div>'; 
echo $social;
    }

    function socialLinkProduct() {
$social = '';
$social ='<div class="addthis_toolbox"><div class="custom_images">';
global $data; 
if($data['facebook_show'] == 1)
$social .= '<a class="addthis_button_facebook" title="'.$data['translation_facebook'].'"><img src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/images/icon-facebook-product-single.png" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="'.$data['translation_facebook'].'" /></a>';            
if($data['twitter_show'] == 1)
$social .= '<a class="addthis_button_twitter" title="'.$data['translation_twitter'].'"><img src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/images/icon-twitter-product-single.png" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="'.$data['translation_twitter'].'" /></a>';  
//if($data['digg_show'] == 1) 
//$social .= '<a class="addthis_button_digg" title="'.$data['translation_digg'].'"><img src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/images/diggIcon.png" width="64" height="64" border="0" alt="'.$data['translation_digg'].'" /></a>';  
//if($data['youtube_show'] == 1)
//$social .= '<div><a class="addthis_button_youtube"><img src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/images/diggIcon.png" width="64" height="64" border="0" alt="Share to Twitter" /></div></a></div>';  
$social .='<a class="addthis_button_more"><img src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/images/icon-more-product-single.png" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="More..." /></a></div><script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-4f3049381724ac5b"></script>';   
if($data['email_show'] == 1) 
$social .= '<a class="emaillink" href="mailto:'.$data['email'].'" title="'.$data['translation_email'].'"></a></div>'; 
echo $social;
    }

    function socialLinkSingle() {
$social = '';
$social ='<div class="addthis_toolbox"><div class="custom_images">';
global $data; 
if($data['facebook_show'] == 1)
$social .= '<a class="addthis_button_facebook" title="'.$data['translation_facebook'].'"><img src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/images/facebookIcon.png" width="64" height="64" border="0" alt="'.$data['translation_facebook'].'" /></a>';            
if($data['twitter_show'] == 1)
$social .= '<a class="addthis_button_twitter" title="'.$data['translation_twitter'].'"><img src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/images/twitterIcon.png" width="64" height="64" border="0" alt="'.$data['translation_twitter'].'" /></a>';  
//if($data['digg_show'] == 1) 
//$social .= '<a class="addthis_button_digg" title="'.$data['translation_digg'].'"><img src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/images/diggIcon.png" width="64" height="64" border="0" alt="'.$data['translation_digg'].'" /></a>';  
//if($data['youtube_show'] == 1)
//$social .= '<div><a class="addthis_button_youtube"><img src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/images/diggIcon.png" width="64" height="64" border="0" alt="Share to Twitter" /></div></a></div>';  
$social .='<a class="addthis_button_more"><img src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/images/socialIconShareMore.png" width="64" height="64" border="0" alt="More..." /></a></div><script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-4f3049381724ac5b"></script>';    
if($data['email_show'] == 1) 
$social .= '<a class="emaillink" href="mailto:'.$data['email'].'" title="'.$data['translation_email'].'"></a></div>'; 
echo $social;
    }
```

The footer.php file

```
    <!-- footerwhat -->
    <?php wp_footer();  ?>
    <!-- footerwhat -->
```

The extra line of code being generated on the home page (the "..." refer to expected code added by wp_footer())

```
    </footer>
    <!-- footer what?! END -->
    ...
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js?domready=1&#038;ver=1'></script>
    ...
    <!-- footer what?! END -->
```

Comment: have you tried searching for parts of the code, like simply the word addthis?

Comment: I have, it was the first thing I tried. "addthis" only shows up in the functions.php file in the longer bit of code I posted or as a class in one of the stylesheets.

Comment: Search for `wp_enqueue_*`...

Comment: I tried searching for wp_enqueue_ as well, but none of them tie to scripts I didn't already search for instances of "addthis".

Comment: Try to find a snippet that prints out all the registered actions on *wp_footer()* or whatever the action name is (see definition of *wp_footer()*).

Comment: If the theme has this plugin bundled, there shall be a folder `/theme/plugin/`, right? What if you delete/rename it? It should break the theme and display a clue about where the heck this is happening... Crappy theme, functions inside functions, embedded plugins :(

Comment: There actually isn't a /theme/plugin/ folder. That's what makes this so frustrating - whatever is inserting that line is really hidden and it bothers me that it's not obvious.

Comment: Fixed by changing `<?php wp_footer() ?>` to `<?php if (is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
remove_action('wp_footer', 'output_inline_js');
wp_admin_bar_render();
echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://yoursite.com/wp-content/themes/mercor/js/gistfile_pmc.js?ver=3.5.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://yoursite.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/jquery-plugins.min.js?ver=1.6.6'></script><script type='text/javascript' src='http://yoursite.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/woocommerce.min.js?ver=1.6.6'></script>"; 
} else {
wp_footer();
}?>`

Answer (score 0):

Answered by OP in comments:

Fixed by changing

`<?php wp_footer() ?>`

to

```
<?php

 if (is_home() || is_front_page() ) { 
     remove_action('wp_footer', 'output_inline_js'); 
     wp_admin_bar_render(); 
     echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://yoursite.com/wp-content/themes/mercor/js/gistfile_pmc.js?ver=3.5.1'>‌​</script> 
     <script type='text/javascript' src='http://yoursite.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/jquery-plugins‌​.min.js?ver=1.6.6'></script>
     <script type='text/javascript' src='http://yoursite.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/wooco‌​mmerce.min.js?ver=1.6.6'></script>";
 } 
 else { 
    wp_footer();
}

?>
```

– mulysasasylum